# Yumatu and the plural in Dev 24

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, grammar-dikduk, ki-teitzei, capital-punishment

Devarim 24:16 makes a statement which is central to Jewish theology.  The posuk makes clear that a father will not be put to death for the sins of his son and that a son will not be put to death for the sins of his father – the gemara develops this to say that neither shall be put to death through the testimony of the other.  Then, to expand on the first part, lest one think that people outside of the family can receive punishment on behalf of others, the verse concludes “ish b’chet’o yumatu” a man, in his own sin, will be put to death.  This idea of banning vicarious expiation of sin through the death of another forms a solid challenge to any religious system predicated on the death of another to atone for the sins of a person who remains, effectively, unpunished.

לֹא-יוּמְתוּ אָבוֹת עַל-בָּנִים, וּבָנִים לֹא-יוּמְתוּ עַל-אָבוֹת:  אִישׁ בְּחֶטְאוֹ, יוּמָתוּ.

However, there is a grammatical problem with the posuk – it states in those final three words “ish (a man) b’chet’o (in his sin) yumatu (*they* will be put to death, or possibly he will be put to death by *them*)” – the final vav turns the word “yumat” into some form of a plural.  This plural form appears only three other times in tanach. In those, the actions of two parties condemned them both to the death penalty (vayikra 20:13, 16, 27). Here, the verse clearly limits the offender and offense to the singular as an explicit shift from the first part of the posuk with reads “lo yumtu avot” that father**s** shall not be put to death (Onkelos translates both "yumtu" and "yumatu" as "y'mootoon" and T"Yonatan has both being "yitkatlun").  The singular verb (yumat) occurs almost 50 times, both in conjunction with “mot” (as in “mot yumat”) and on its own.  Why would this verse switch to a pluralized action and to what does the plural refer? What doesn’t the posuk simply read “ish b’chet’o yumat”?

Answer (score 4):

[Sifri (Devarim 280)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34328&st=&pgnum=177) understands this last clause to be stating an exception to the rule about vicarious punishment: "Fathers [or, per Gra's note: adults] die for their own sins, but sons [Gra: minors] may die for their parents' sins," G-d forbid. (See also [Shabbos 32b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=32b&format=pdf), which lists several sins that may bear such consequences.)

So the plural form fits with this: "each man, for his sins, they [his children]..."

(Which may also explain why the verse in Kings that DoubleAA cited indeed changes the form: there this particular detail isn't relevant, since it refers specifically to Divine punishment rather than the human-imposed kind.)

Comment: The way the _Tora T'mima_ understands this _Sifre_, the word "man" in "each man shall die for his sins" is being picked on by the _Sifre_ to exclude children: according to that, the _yumasu_ applies to the adults, not the children, which means that the _Sifre_ doesn't help answer the question above. But it may well be that your way of reading the _Sifre_ is a valid alternative to the _TT_'s.

Comment: @alex so the ish is the father and the plural in yumatu is his sons? Why would the text switch from avot to ish when referring to the same relationship and presenting a subtlety in a subcategory?

Comment: @Dan: because the key is the difference between בנים in general (who don't suffer for their father's sins) and those who are not איש (see msh210's comment).

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to the Navi ([II Kings 14:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09b14.htm#6)) it does say it that way:

> ‏...כַּכָּתוּב בְּסֵפֶר תּוֹרַת-מֹשֶׁה אֲשֶׁר-צִוָּה יְהוָה לֵאמֹר, לֹא-יוּמְתוּ אָבוֹת עַל-בָּנִים וּבָנִים לֹא-יוּמְתוּ עַל-אָבוֹת--כִּי אִם-אִישׁ בְּחֶטְאוֹ, יוּמָת‏
>   ...according to that which is written in the book of the law of Moses, as the LORD commanded saying: 'The fathers shall not be put to death for the children, nor the children be put to death for the fathers; but every man shall be put to death for his own sin.'

Comment: all that does is intensify the question on the grammar in devarim

Comment: @Dan It raises much stronger questions than that.

Comment: @DoubleAA: not any more than the fact that the Gemara frequently paraphrases pesukim rather than quoting them word for word.

Comment: @Alex This pasuk doesn't give any obvious indication that it is paraphrasing. Also, it seems odd to paraphrase one letter off the end of a word, especially if that letter is as significant as the question implies.

Comment: @DoubleAA: it's not just the one letter, though - there's also the added כי אם.

Comment: @Alex Those two words can very easily be read as the voice of a background commentator (like a 'rashi'): " 'It's not this' but rather 'it's this' ".

Comment: @Alex Of course, those two words can also be seen as part of a different version of the pasuk. The answer has to be that the Navi did some editing in applying it to his situation, or at least that the navi text is the corrupt one (much easier to swallow than the alternative). I just don't think the question is as simple as your examples in the gemara where it's clear that the gemara is not trying to quote in a formal sense, not to even touch on all the places where the gemara's text differs from ours. BTW cf. DivII25:4 for a third version of the pasuk.

Comment: could it be as simple as saying that the plural is "the people who put him to death which must be at least 2 eidim" so the text is "a man, in his own sins, they will put him to death". That wouldn't exactly be clear but it would account for a shift to the plural as a reminder of the judicial process requiring more than one witness.

Comment: @Dan: then the last word would have to be ימיתו rather than יומתו, which is passive.

Comment: @DoubleAA: I see where [Daas Soferim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39786&pgnum=544) explains that indeed the navi is paraphrasing the pasuk - since the formal meaning of it (as in the Sifri I quoted, and from there in Sanhedrin 27b, as mentioned in the original question) is that relatives can't testify against each other, and that the sense in which Amatziah followed it is "only" the simple surface meaning. Which works with what you said about כי אם being the navi's interjection into the verse, but also fits with my idea that therefore he deliberately misquoted the last word.

Comment: @Alex how about "a man, in his own sin, will be put to death by them"